# call Logout api on browser close in blazor webassembly

Tags: javascript, blazor-webassembly, browser-close

how to call logout api on browser close by user. I have applied Ajax call to archive this but it works perfectly fine in local host but not work in "Linux Server" can anyone help me to find the solution.

Comment: [more](https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+browser+close+event+blazor+site:stackoverflow.com)